# ServiceBusClient SendMessageAsync very slow

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I have the following method that I'm debugging in vscode:

```cs
public async Task PublishReport(string correlationId)
    {
        _methodName = nameof(GetReport);
        _correlationId = correlationId;
        LogInfo("Started");

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime lastPoll = await GetTimeOfLastPoll(_correlationId);

        List<AmxGetReportResponse> reportRecs = await GetReport(lastPoll, _correlationId);
        var credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
                                new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
                                new VisualStudioCredential(),
                                new AzureCliCredential()
                                );
        LogInfo($"Now logged into azure");
        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient($"{_amxOptions.ServiceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net", credential);
        LogInfo($"Have service bus client");
        var topicSendClient = serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_amxOptions.ServiceBusTopicName);
        LogInfo($"Have topic sender");

        foreach (var reportRec in reportRecs)
        {
            string msg = _amxReport2CatsUpdate.Execute(reportRec);
            LogInfo($"Mapped msg={msg}");
            var serviceBusMsg = new ServiceBusMessage(msg);
            LogInfo($"Have service bus message");
            await topicSendClient.SendMessageAsync(serviceBusMsg);
            LogInfo($"Sent msg to sb topic {_amxOptions.ServiceBusTopicName}: {msg}");
        }

        await SetTimeOfLastPoll(now, _correlationId);
        LogInfo("Leaving");
    }
```

It does work and will publish a message for each record of the report. The total size of the report xml is 30k and each record is approx 1k.

My problem is, it takes roughly 1 min 45 seconds for the SendMessageAsync method to run?

Comment: I am not sure I follow precisely why you need to login and specify topic pr item in the report. I would try to create a DateTime before each function, and then log that DateTime - DateTime.Now after. 

Then you would know which specific method that is causing a slow down. There is no way a send should take 1 min and 45 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Morten. I have corrected so login only once but still face the problem with the line that sends the message. I know it's that line because the log statements in the vscode terminal window are timestamped

Comment: The calls `_amxReport2CatsUpdate.Execute()` and `SetTimeOfLastPoll()` what do those do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Bus clients are intended to be long-lived and, ideally, treated as singletons. *([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#client-lifetime))*

The pattern that you're using here requires that a new connection be created, authentication be performed, a link opened, and authorization to be performed for each call to `PublishReport`.  Because all of that happens lazily when the first service operation is requested, your first call to `SendMessagesAsync` is paying the cost.

I suspect that the majority of the time is being spent attempting to acquire a credential.  I'd suggest [collecting Azure.Identity logs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#enable-and-configure-logging) to help understand what credential is being selected and whether failures/retries are taking place.  The approach described in that guide will also capture Service Bus logs, which emit an entry when sending starts and completes which would allow you to calculate how long the actual service operation took. Specifically, you'll be looking for events 1, 2, and 3, from the "Azure-Messaging-ServiceBus" [event source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Diagnostics/ServiceBusEventSource.cs).

It is also worth noting that the Service Bus clients are not disposed by `PublishReport`, which will orphan connections until they timeout, potentially causing delays due to contention in the network stack.